# Can't figure out how to use Enums with a listbox

Tags: c#, enums

So for my programming midterm I have to create a haunted house. It's required that we use Enums. I'm having trouble calling the Enums in my other form.

This is the code from the form that i'm trying to get to use the Enums in the listbox.

```
private void lstRooms_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string  room = lstRooms.Text;

        RoomChoice rooms = new RoomChoice(room);

        if (room = "Den")
        {

        }
        if (room = "DH")
        {

        }
        if (room = "UH")
        {

        }
        if (room = "Bedroom")
        {

        }
        if (room = "Basement")
        {

        }
        if (room = "Greenhouse")
        {

        }
        if (room = "Attic")
        {

        }
        if (room = "WW")
        {

        }
```

This is the code for the Enums.

```
class RoomChoice
{
    public string room;

    public RoomChoice(string room)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        this.room = room;
    }
     public enum Room
    {
        Den, 
        DH,
        UH,
        Bedroom,
        Basement,
        Greenhouse,
        Attic,
        WW

    }

    class DecideRoom
    {
        public Room roomchoice { get; set; }

        public void DecideRooms(string room)
        {
            roomchoice = (Room)Enum.Parse(typeof(Room), room);
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry if it's a super obvious mistake, I'm very new to C# and Enums are confusing to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That ll not answer to you question but, you should use `switch()` instead of `if()`

Comment: Do you really need that whole `RoomChoice` class? Why not just store their choice as an `enum`? There are already methods you can use to convert strings to enums and vice versa.

Comment: So how would I go about storing their choice as an Enum?

Comment: You cannot do this: `if (room = "Den")` because `=` is an assignment operator. If you do that you will get this erro: *Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'* because that expression does not evaluate to a bool. You need to use equality operator which is 2 equal signs: `if (room == "Den")`. Do not use strings, see my answer.

Comment: Damn, I'm an idiot. I was using == before when I was setting up the Enums, but I was getting a lot of errors so I changed it to = thinking I messed up.

Answer (score 1):

This is the enum:

```
public enum Room
{
    Den,
    DH,
    UH,
    Bedroom,
    Basement,
    Greenhouse,
    Attic,
    WW
}
```

This is how you bind it to a listbox:

```
yourListBox.DataSource = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof (Room));
```

Here is how you get the selected value:

```
private void yourListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selected = (Room)yourListBox.SelectedItem;
    // Do whatever you need to...
}
```

---

**Some Suggestions**

Use a switch in your `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler and do whatever you need to-you will get intellisence support and compiler support instead of writing strings such as "DEN" and then realize the casing is wrong. Plus it is cleaner. Like this:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.listBox1.SelectedIndex < 0) return;
    var selected = (Room)this.listBox1.SelectedItem;

    switch (selected)
    {
        case Room.Den:
            // Do whatever you need to...
            break;
        case Room.DH:
            break;
        case Room.UH:
            break;
        case Room.Bedroom:
            break;
        case Room.Basement:
            break;
        case Room.Greenhouse:
            break;
        case Room.Attic:
            break;
        case Room.WW:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Right now my problem is sorta that all the if statements are errors because "Room" is a string and Enums are considered bools, or i'm attempting to convert to a bool somehow.    
              Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Comment: @ColeBrowne what do you mean *Enums are considered bools*?

Comment: That isn't really what I meant to say, sorry my brain hurts from this. I've been trying to figure it out for multiple hours. What I mean is my code thinks im trying to convert a string into a bool so i'm just getting an error for every if statement. I'm just confused on why that's happening